# How can I update dynamic IP from pfsense box, using my own DNS server?

Tags: bind, dynamic-dns, pfsense, dynamic-ip

Ok, let me try to put this together. I have one pfsense box with one dynamic IP address, and on another location (other country) I'm running VPS with my DNS server (bind9).

So now, I want to make that dynamic IP from the pfsense box is updated whenever is renewed. Updated where? In my DNS server:

Suppose I have something like this:

```
pfsense.mydomain.bla.   IN  A   -my dynamic IP-
```

I never did this, so I don't have much experience with this kind of configuration and I know that I can use free dynamic dns service, but I want to try with my own DNS server.

Is`RFC2136`solution for me or something else?

Comment: I just use freedns.afraid.org; I suspect you could see what Josh uses (though I think it's a "wrote it himself" deal, from the site news updates.) http://freedns.afraid.org/news/

Answer (score 1):

You have to have a DNS server that supports dynamic IP.  AFAIK, there's no single way that the address update works against the DNS server.  I've seen it implemented in lots of different ways.

**edit**

Look here.

http://blog.philippklaus.de/2014/08/deploy-your-own-bind9-based-ddns-server/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this done with Bind9, but I have seen it done with Cloudflare and their API. Updating the A/AAAA record should be a simple matter of checking for the existing external IP, storing it as a variable, and calling the Cloudflare API to update or create a new record.